# Is it possible to get a React property outside of React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component called `MyComponent`. Inside of the component, I have a defined string property called `myProperty`. Is there a way to get the value of `myProperty` from outside of any React component? Particularly from the browser console?

I should mention: I can't edit the React component directly, so I can't set it to a cookie or a window property. I noticed that Facebook somehow is able to access the properties with the React Devtools extension.

Comment: I believe it is out of scope and won't be accessible... but you can use an "intermediate storage", I mean, you could write it to a cookie or put temporarily the information in a hidden field...

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to access it from the console for debugging purposes?

If so, you can simply set it to the window object by typing this inside your React function:

```
window.someVariableName = myProperty;
```

Open the console and type **someVariableName** to get its value.

Comment: I don't have direct access to the React component, so I can't actually do that. I'll edit my question to include that info though.